# Return entire object not just key in js with filter

Tags: javascript

I currently have some data in a firebase db that contains multiple members like so:

```
membersData: {
    uid1: {
        first: 'blah'
        last: 'blah'
        mStatus: true
    }
    uid2: {
        first: 'blah'
        last: 'blah'
        mStatus: true
    }
    uid3: {
        first: 'blah'
        last: 'blah'
        mStatus: false
    }
}
```

To filter over my data I run this:

```
Object.keys(membersData).filter(member => membersData[member].mStatus == true)
```

However this only returns an array of the uid. How can I get it to return the uid but also the first, last and mStatus?

Comment: FYI: `== true` can be omitted since `membersData[member].mStatus` already resolves to a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting only the **keys** with `Object.keys`. All the further computations are done on that **array of keys**. You can use a `.map()` again to get the items in the requested format.

You might simply use a different method like `Object.values()` if you are only concerned about the values and not the keys:

```js
let membersData = {
    'uid1' : {
        'first': 'blah',
        'last': 'blah',
       'mStatus': true
    },
    'uid2': {
        'first': 'blah',
        'last': 'blah',
        'mStatus': true
    },
    'uid3': {
        'first': 'blah',
        'last': 'blah',
        'mStatus': false
    }
}

let ans = Object.keys(membersData).filter(member => membersData[member].mStatus == true).map(x => { return { [x] : membersData[x]} } );

console.log(ans);

let ans2 = Object.values(membersData).filter(member => member.mStatus == true);
console.log(ans2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the keys, because you are running from `Object.keys`.

Try running with `Object.values` to return the values you want:

```
Object.values(membersData).filter(member => member.mStatus == true);
```